# Differences between "while" and "when"

Tags: word-choice

1. Every single day *while* I sit to write, I am to think what I will write.
2. Every single day *when* I sit to write, I am to think what I will write.

From *while* and *when*, which will you prefer and why? If it is possible, please say another word that can used instead of *while* and *when* in this case.

Comment: "I am to think" is awkward.

Comment: "Am|is|are to" (i.e.= must) is not used very much nowadays, but it's not an archaism by any means, and in certain kinds of formal writing it wouldn't be considered awkward.  *All are to stand when the judge enters the courtroom.*

Comment: It's not archaic at all, no, but it's overtly formal.

Comment: Who wrote those sentences? Did you write them yourself? Both look very awkward.

Comment: @Rathony, you are right. I have write them myself. Since these sentences seem awkward, please write the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the temporal sense,

"While" deals with a **duration**,

> While I was sleeping, he stole my phone.

"when" deals with some **specific point** in time.

> When I went to bed, he stole my phone.

In your case, I prefer

> Every single day when I sit to write, I am to think what I will write.

Answer (score 1):

I would use your option 2:

> Every single day **when** I sit to write, I should start with thinking about what exactly I will write.

---

The second option focuses too much on the process of **sitting**:

> Every single day **while** I sit to write, I am to think what I will write.

It's hard for me to construe a situation where this sentence would be felicitous. Maybe you have two chairs. On the first chair, you "sit to write": the chair is used solely for sitting and thinking about *what exactly* to write. The second chair is used when you've finally decided what it is that you should write.

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle differences between the meaning of the two sentences.

> "*While* I sit to write"

refers to the entire period of time spent sitting.

> "*When* I sit to write"

refers to the action of sitting down; i.e. one specific moment.